# Как подключить несколько плейлистов m3u8 в плеер?

Tags: javascript, mediaplayer

Как вставить в плеер несколько плейлистов с разным качеством видео 360 480 ?
На сайте разработчика написано вставить в html.

Другими словами нужно эти 2 плейлиста подключить к скрипту

```
<video controls crossorigin playsinline 
    poster="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-HD.jpg" 
    id="player">
<source
    src="https://bl.webcaster.pro/media/playlist/a13deaa5721c831a2b68b6983ff0100e/2_70430/480p/ca9b9125037cd539b61a2ff46366f6b0/1552260702.m3u8"
    type="video/mp4"
    size="480"
/>
<source
    src="https://bl.webcaster.pro/media/playlist/a13deaa5721c831a2b68b6983ff0100e/2_70430/360p/ca9b9125037cd539b61a2ff46366f6b0/1552260702.m3u8"
    type="video/mp4"
    size="360"
/>
</video>
```

Пример с одним плейлистом

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
 
 const source = 'https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8'; 
 
 const video = document.querySelector('video');
 
 // For more options see: https://github.com/sampotts/plyr/#options
 // captions.update is required for captions to work with hls.js
 const player = new Plyr(video, {captions: {active: true, update: true, language: 'en'}});
 
 if (!Hls.isSupported()) {
  video.src = source;
 } else {
  // For more Hls.js options, see https://github.com/dailymotion/hls.js
  const hls = new Hls();
  hls.loadSource(source);
  hls.attachMedia(video);
  window.hls = hls;
  
  // Handle changing captions
  player.on('languagechange', () => {
   // Caption support is still flaky. See: https://github.com/sampotts/plyr/issues/994
   setTimeout(() => hls.subtitleTrack = player.currentTrack, 50);
  });
 }
 
 // Expose player so it can be used from the console
 window.player = player;
});
```

```css
.container {
 margin: 40px auto;
 width: 400px;
}
video {
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/plyr@3/dist/plyr.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/plyr@3"></script>
<div class="container">
 <video controls crossorigin playsinline poster="https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/poster.png"></video>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/video-dev/hls.js/18bb552/dist/hls.min.js"></script>
```

Это мой пример https://codepen.io/stopani/pen/ZPyNKg
Документация https://github.com/sampotts/plyr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Plyr смотрит в дочерние элементы, ищет `<source>`, на основе которых строит меню плеера.
2. При выборе качества Plyr записывает в евент сурс, выбранного варианта.
3. Эвентом `changequality` можно поймать событие, вытащить новый сурс и записать его в `<video src="">` и в `hls.loadSource`
4. Остается только переаттачить `video` и `hls` через `hls.attachMedia(video)`

Возможно, предварительно надо `hls.detachMedia()` делать, но я могу и ошибаться.
Для того, чтобы использовать свои сурсы, просто замените в блоках `<source>` атрибут `<src>`

p.s. В примере указаны 2 одинаковых линка с одинаковым качеством для демонстрации.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    let video = document.querySelector('video');
    //source берем из аттрибута первого <source>
    video.source = video.children[0].getAttribute("src")

    let player = new Plyr(video, { captions: { active: true, update: true, language: 'en' } });
    let hls = new Hls();

    if (Hls.isSupported()) {
        hls.attachMedia(video);
        hls.on(Hls.Events.MEDIA_ATTACHED, function() {
            hls.loadSource(video.source);
        });
    }
    //Эвент смены сурса
    player.on('qualitychange', event => {
        video.source = event.detail.plyr.source;
        hls.loadSource(video.source)
        hls.attachMedia(video);
    });
    
    window.player = player;
})
```

```css
.container {
 margin: 40px auto;
 width: 400px;
}
video {
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/plyr@3/dist/plyr.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/plyr@3"></script>
<div class="container">
 <video controls crossorigin playsinline poster="https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/poster.png">
  <source
    src="https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8"
    type="video/mp4"
    size="480"
/>
<source
    src="https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8"
    type="video/mp4"
    size="360"
/>
  
  </video>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/video-dev/hls.js/18bb552/dist/hls.min.js"></script>
```